# Mac Safari stops loading page from time to time

Tags: macos, safari

From time to time, I experience issue which Safari is not loading a page. Suddenly none of the links from a page loads. Even reload does not work. In all the cases, Safari appears to be loading a page but progress bar only moves a little and then halted. However, if I right click on a link and open on a new tab, the page loads.

This happens when I am running El Capitan and also happens after I upgraded to Sierra. Amazon.com, ebay.com are some of the sites that I have had problems. I have cleared the cookies and all cache and problem still returns.

I do not have any adblocker installed on Safari. I don't even have flash installed.

What might be the problem?

Comment: I've always figured it was a safari bug. I've been plagued by some form of this or another since 10.2 (Jaguar) on totally different computers. Only the frequency and the workarounds that work have changed. I'm interested to know the answer, too :)